# Angular directive for simulating a mouseenter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a directive for simulating a mouseenter event ?

I've tried searching for one but all I've found is the directive which binds a function to the mouse over or karma tests for simulating mouse over.

My use case is that I all ready have a event binded to mouse over but I'm looking for a directive in the form of `simulate-mouse ="shouldBeMouseOver"` such that when `$scope.shouldBeMouseOver` is true the element I place the directive on reacts as if it has mouseenter event.

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to use a scope variable and something like `ng-class` ?

Comment: there's other behaviour at work on the element which I can not change that is why I'm going the round about route of simulating a mouse over.

Comment: you would have to create an event object then that includes coordinates and trigger the mouseover

Comment: even if I'm triggering the mouseover on the element which has the directive on it, because I would have access to the element itself

Comment: have a button named `mouse enter` and click on it should do the simulation...

Comment: my guess is there are easier ways to do what you need, just not sure what the behaviors are without seeing them like in a demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPTATE!**
Previous solution was a workaround. You can now use an angular directive for that(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseenter).

```
ng-mouseenter="handler()"
```

**Previous solution (workaround)**

HTML:

```
    <div simulate-mouse eventhandle="objfromscope">Hover</div> <!-- objfromscope: true or false -->
   <div ng-click="objfromscope=!objfromscope">Enable/Disable hover</div>
```

Directive

```
app.directive('simulateMouse', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            eventhandle : '=eventhandle' //eventhandle is two way data binded
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            
            scope.$watch(function() {
                    return scope.eventhandle;
                }, function(newValue) {
                    console.log(newValue)
                  if(newValue){
                     element.off("mouseenter").on("mouseenter",function(){
                           onMouseOverCall()
                        });
                }else{
                    element.off("mouseenter");
                }

                });
           
           var onMouseOverCall = function(){ /* called only when eventhandle is true */
               console.log("hoho") 
           }
        }
    };
});
```